# JAVA: unmappable character (0x92) for encoding GBK

Tags: java, stddraw

I am able to run this on the eclipse but I can't run it using sublime3, how's it that?

```
       public class TestStdDraw {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.05);
       StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
       StdDraw.point(0.5, 0.5);
       StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.MAGENTA);
       StdDraw.line(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2);
   }
```

}

and following the not that Note: ".\StdDraw.java uses or overrides a deprecated API." and "Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.", it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Show your entire file, not just the Java parts that seem relevant. The unmappable character error normally happens with files that contain non-ASCII characters that aren't compatible with the platform's default encoding.

Comment: Also note that neither errors are supposed to be blocking. They're warnings and it should still run fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue when using the StdDraw is caused by your system locale, try to change your system locale to US English, or compile with the encoding flag:

> javac -encoding UTF8 TestStdDraw.java